# Execute a charge from existing customer with card in Stripe out of iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I have a very hard time figuring out how to do this from the iOS app programmatically.

Im using (besides other) the following classes from github:
https://github.com/hybrdthry911/ELStripe

Class: **ELCharge.m**

```
+(ELCharge *)charge{
   return [[ELCharge alloc]init];
}

(*****************code in between ************************)

 //Will attempt to charge either a customer or card. Exactly one must exist   
per charge. If multiple or neither exist an exception will be raised.
//Warning: This is the final step it will APPLY A CHARGE TO THE 
ACCOUNT.

-(void)createChargeWithCompletion:(ELChargeCompletionBlock)handler{
    [ELCharge createCharge:self completion:handler];
}

+(void)createCharge:(ELCharge *)charge completion
 (ELChargeCompletionBlock)handler{
 NSError *chargeError;
     if (![charge validForProcessingWithError:&chargeError]) {
          handler(nil,chargeError);
          return;
     }

     if (!chargeError) {
          [ELStripe executeStripeCloudCodeWithMethod:@"POST"    
           prefix:@"charges" parameters:[ELCharge 
           dictionaryForCreatingCharge:charge] completionHandler:^(id 
           jsonObject, NSError *error) {
           handler([ELCharge 
           chargeFromParseStripeDictionary:jsonObject],error);
       }];
   }
}
```

In the iOS class, I do the following in order to create a test charge:

```
//create an automatic charge in stripe from an existing customer with card   
attached to him
-(void) executeChargeInStripe:(UIButton*)sender
{

     ELCharge *charge = [ELCharge charge];

    //Assign the charge properties
    charge.customerID = @"cus_72xvQI6Q5IC9it";
    charge.currency = @"USD";
    NSNumber *chargeAmount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:111];
    charge.amountInCents = chargeAmount;


//Call ChargeMethod from Github Framework
[ELCharge createCharge:charge completion:^(ELCharge *charge, NSError 
*error)    {
    if (!error)  {
    //code for normal handling
        NSLog(@"Charge has been made successfully");
    } else {
        // error code handling
        NSLog(@"Charge NOT made");

    }
}];

}
```

Im passing this to the following clould code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("stripeHTTPRequest", function(request, response) 
{
//Check for valid pre/suf/postfixes, if they are not there do not include    
them.
var prefix = request.params["prefix"];
var suffix = "";
var postfix = "";
var secondPostfix = "";
if (!isEmpty(request.params["suffix"])) suffix =  
    '/'+request.params['suffix'];  
if (!isEmpty(request.params["postfix"])) postfix = 
    '/'+request.params['postfix'];   
if (!isEmpty(request.params["secondPostfix"])) secondPostfix = 
    '/'+request.params['secondPostfix'];

 //call from parse to stripe done by http request as parse/stripe api 
   uncomplete
   Parse.Cloud.httpRequest(
   {
        method: request.params["method"],
        //Create URL from base url and pre/suf/postfixes
        url: 'https://'+STRIPE_API_BASE_URL + prefix + suffix + postfix + 
               secondPostfix,
               headers: {
                  'Authorization': "Bearer " + STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
                         },
              params:request.params["params"],
              success: function(httpResponse) 
             {
               //response text is a json dictionary
                 response.success(httpResponse.text);
             },
        error: function(httpResponse) 
        {
            response.error(httpResponse.text);
        }
  });
});
```

Im now getting the following error:
 Charge NOT made (my error message from the IOS class I created).

Im really surprised that I recieve neither an error in Parse Cloud nor in Stripe.
If for example, I use an already used token instead of the customerID, I have an error in both. So the connection seems to work I assume, maybe there is something which I do wrong in the iOS class.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate more. Did you log the error? Was there an error on parse's side in the console log?

Answer (score 0):

have you reverted your Parse JavaScript SDK to 1.5.0?  Anything past 1.5.0 is no longer supported.